# What logic am I missing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `#wrapper` div wrap a `#pane` div, the #wrapper, `overflow-x:scroll.`
What I want to do is while I touch the `#wrapper`,the `#pane` should follow my finger moving.

my code is

```
$('#wrapper').on('touchmove',function(event){
    var touch = event.originalEvent.targetTouches[0];
    var move_x = touch.pageX;
    $('#wrapper').scrollLeft(move_x);                   
})
```

The result is : Yes the #pane is following my finger just in reverse direction, but when my finger leave and touch again, the #pane scroll location jump to my finger x position instantly, that's not what I want. The #pane shouldn't move when I touch it until I drag around it.

Comment: Is me saying use $('#wrapper').scrollRight(move_x); ridiculous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont want it to jump to your finger location, you will have to store the current position, and move it based on the difference between the original location that you touch, and the end location that you stop touching.

Comment: Ok I just made it, and thx for the scrollRight, I thought it only has scrollLeft. But i didn't use touchend